# Задача по golang каналы. Помогите понять, правильно ли я понял задание и что не так с решением

Tags: golang

[Задание](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OB2cu.jpg)

Вот моё решение, на проверке пишет WA

```
package main
func main() {
}
func Merge2Channels (f func(int)int , in1 <-chan int, in2 <- chan int, out chan<- int, n int){

    go func(){
        for i := 0; i < n; i++{
        out <-(f(<-in1) + f(<-in2))
        }
    }()

}
```

Проверял таким способом

```
package main
import "fmt"
func main() {
n :=2
in1 := make(chan int,2)
in2 := make(chan int,2)
out := make(chan int)
Merge2Channels (f,in1,in2,out,n)
in1<-4
in2<-5
in1<-3
in2<-6

fmt.Println(<-out)
fmt.Println(<-out)

}
func Merge2Channels (f func(int)int , in1 <-chan int, in2 <- chan int, out chan<- int, n int){

    go func(){
        for i := 0; i < n; i++{
        out <-(f(<-in1) + f(<-in2))
        }
    }()

}
func f (i int) int {
    return (i*i)
}
```

Что собственно не так? Merge2Channels не блокирует ничего, если каналы буфферизованные, я же не знаю что они там подают.
P.S. Если что выглядит не так не судите строго, это мой hello world на golang.

Comment: А если не писать однострочник `out <-(f(<-in1) + f(<-in2))` а вызвать функцию сначала с первым аргументом, а затем со вторым и сохранить результат в x1, x2, как написано в задании?. Ведь функция возможно хранит какое-то состояние и её результат будет отличаться если ей вначале передать второе число, а потом первое и наоборот.

Answer (score 1):

Тут все гораздно сложнее.

1. каналы будут отдавать числа в определенном порядке, и в этом же порядке
   нам нужно писать в 3ий канал. При этом вычисления над каждой парой
   имеют разные интервалы: какое-то медленнее, какое-то быстрее.
2. по 2 корутины при чтении из 2х каналов;
3. по 2 корутины при вычислении над каждым числом f(x);
4. накапливание результата в массиве с жестко заданной длиной.

корутина при записи в 3ий канал.

Пункты 2 и 5 не удалось проверить. Локально все работает. Но их лядский сервер на один и тот же (отличались комменты) выдавал:

```
'/temp/compiling/source' cannot be extracted via extract () /bin/sh ./build.sh
```

Лучший результат без этих пунктов 2.009 секунды. Почти, но не ОК.

При это пробовал перезапускать точно рабочие решения на Python (Другие задачи) и SQL - когда запускается, когда нет. В общем, очевидно, что неполадки на сервере, уж в прогамме "сложить 2 числа" миддл ошибаться не может.

Сжег 60 итераций. И забил, после того как подтвердилось, что 1 код (даже на python|C++|SQL) выдает разные рузультаты.

Answer (score 1):

У меня тоже не вышло выполнить на OK.
Мне удалось воссоздать такие ошибки перечисленные в ТЗ:

- Блокировку функции (WA + логи)
- Неверные вычисления (WA + логи)
- Считывание большего кол-ва значений чем нужно (WA + логи)
- Считывание меньше (WA + логи)
- Слижком долгое выполнение (IL)

Пожалуй не удалось только привысить объем памяти..
Но при этом все равно упирался в какую-то ошибку с WA, но с пустыми логами..

Учитывая, что время на решение по сути закончилось [вот мои варианты](https://github.com/FreeNickName/ContestOzonGolangSchool2020)
Самый простой, который проходит IL

```
import "sync"

func Merge2Channels(f func(int) int, in1 <-chan int, in2 <-chan int, out chan<- int, n int) {
    go func() {
        var wg sync.WaitGroup
        var x1, x2 int
        for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
            wg.Add(2)
            go func() {
                defer wg.Done()
                x1 = f(<-in1)
            }()
            go func() {
                defer wg.Done()
                x2 = f(<-in2)
            }()
            wg.Wait()
            out <- x1 + x2
        }
    }()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Интересно, топику несколько лет. А я только вчера решал эту задачу.
Сегодня пошел искать новые задачи по каналам, чтобы попрактиковаться - наткнулся на этот топик.

На всякий, приложу свои размышления и решение.

1. В данном случае нам необходимо распараллелить запуск `fn()` так как именно эта функция может выполняться N время по условиям задачи.
2. Таким образом нам нужно параллельно вычитать значения из каналов, и также параллельно применить к ним вычисления из `fn()`

Прежде чем смотреть решение, рекомендую попробовать продумать самостоятельно.

**Решение**
Намеренно оставил все так, как решил изначально. Можно улучшить.

```
func merge2Channels(fn func(int) int, in1 <-chan int, in2 <-chan int, out chan<- int, n int) {
    
    type t struct {
        i int
        n int
    }

    ch1 := make(chan t)
    ch2 := make(chan t)
    
    for i := 0; i < n; i ++ {
        go func(num int){
            x1 := <- in1
            ch1 <- t{i: num, n: fn(x1)}
        }(i)
    }
    for i := 0; i < n; i ++ {
        go func(num int){
            x2 := <- in2
            ch2 <- t{i: num, n: fn(x2)}
        }(i)
    }
    

    go func(){
        x1sl := make([]t, 0, n)
        x2sl := make([]t, 0, n)
    
        for i := 0; i < n; i ++{
            x1sl = append(x1sl, <- ch1)
            x2sl = append(x2sl, <- ch2)
        }
        
        for _, x1 := range x1sl {
            for _, x2 := range x2sl {
                if x1.i == x2.i {
                    out <- x1.n + x2.n
                    break
                }
            }
        }
    }()
}
```

> Passed. OK. Время работы: 5.202761ms.